# django how to redirect to homepage from within a template

Tags: django, redirect, django-templates, django-views

Okay, so basically my homepage ('^$') is a log in page and after the user logs in, it sends him to another page where a log out button. In my template, the log out button is just a link.

```
<a href="">Logout</a>
```

what should it say inside the href? Normally if I want to redirect to a different view, I would put the views name in the quotation marks but the home page view is just '^$' so I tried leaving it blank inside the quotations which didn't work. I also tried doing

```
<a href="/^$">Logout</a>
```

which failed miserably. Any idea on how to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
<a href="">Logout</a>
```

would refer to the current page (basically a page reload)

Try:

```
<a href="/">Logout</a>
```

If that `localhost:8000/` is the URL you are trying to target

The recommended way is:

```
<a href="{% url myapp.views.home_page %}">Logout</a>
```

Where `myapp` and `home_page` refer to the app name, and the view name respectively.

Alternatively, [You can Name a URL Pattern](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/#naming-url-patterns):

```
url(r"^$", 'my_view', name="homepage")
```

Now, you would do

```
<a href="{% url homepage %}">Logout</a>
```

If >django 1.5,

```
<a href="{% url 'homepage' %}">Logout</a>
```

Comment: Ah, perfect. I think I should just change all my links to {%%} tags. Thanks! So uhm in my views, if I want to redirect to another view, for example, "if user is not None: auth.login(request, user) return redirect('/loggedin_view/')" can I just do "return redirect({% url myapp.views.loggedin_view %})" ?

Comment: In a view, `{%%}` wont work. You can use `redirect(reverse('myapp.views.loggedin_view'))`

Comment: hm wait, so when I changed it to "a href="{% url myapp.views.home_page %}" it gave me an error saying "'url' requires a non-empty first argument. The syntax changed in Django 1.5, see the dos." I'm guessing I should put quotes around the "myapp.views.home_page"? Okay adding the quotes worked. perfect.

Comment: hmm.. what does redirect(reverse()) do?

Comment: reverse computes the url path from the view method. and redirect would redirect to the path . Django tutorial covers this pretty well